# Rotate animation to an ImageView in FrameLayout does not take effect

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview

I have one `ImageView` in `FrameLayout`, and apply rotate animation to it. However, the animation does not take effect.

The animation resource file anim_blog.xml(located in `res/anim`):

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <rotate
         android:fromDegrees="0.0"
         android:toDegrees="360.0"
         android:pivotX="50%p"
         android:pivotY="50%p"
         android:repeatCount="infinite"
         android:duration="1200" />
</set>
```

The code in `Activity` is listed below:

```
Animation rotateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mCtx, R.anim.anim_blog);
rotateAnim.setDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
mProgressIV.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

Comment: add your xml and where are you writing this code snippet?

Comment: The code is written in onResume() method of the activity.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting animation duration too large, change it as follows :

```
Animation rotateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mCtx, R.anim.anim_blog);
mProgressIV.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
```

Comment: way too large, as the value represents milliseconds - my pocket calculator says one rotation will take almost 25 days :)

Answer (score 0):

please try what has done successfully from my end:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim_blog);
    image.startAnimation(animation);
```

I created example [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4E1qxhiuLQ6eHoxMkMwTDg5YlE/view?usp=sharing), you can check it out.